# Debug DLL function parameters without a source code

Tags: debugging, dll

I have a DLL without a source code. I know that a certain program (again, I have only a binary file, no source code) runs this DLL to perform a task. I already viewed this DLL with Dependency Walker (depends.exe) to see names of the functions. Now I would like to see what parameters are sent to a certain function by the program. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about a native DLL? If so, then the answer is perhaps.

If the DLL was compiled using C++ name mangling, then it's possible for depends to get the original prototype back. If the function names look something like ?_Foo@ADBDE Instead of Foo, then they're decorated. In dependency walker use the "Undecorate C++ Functions" command.

Otherwise, you need to get the module address of the function and use a disassembler to work out what parameters are used and what they do. This can be a very frustrating and time consuming task.

Comment: I am able to see function name and its parameters after I undecorate them. The thing is that I want to see what is sent to the function "in action" - I would like to have an insight into the invocation of this DLL function and what it receives.

Comment: @Jacek That's much more complicated. I imagine you would have to attach the debugger to the DLL once loaded by the application, and then set breakpoints at the function addresses. You'll still only get assembler though without any debugging information. You'll have the stack trace but it'll be just a list of addresses. Making sense of parameters in x86 and how they apply in C++ will be difficult.

If you have the functions and their parameters, it might be worth firing test values in and seeing what results you get out. You must have some idea of what's being sent in?